# what is the best way to create a class of global constants in Swift

Tags: swift

In Objective-C, we used to do the following in our class files:

In the header:

```
extern NSString* const kSTRING_CONSTANT;
```

In the implementation:

```
NSString* const kSTRING_CONSTANT = @"a_string_constant";
```

What is the Swift equivalent of this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to deal with that type of constants is to create a Struct

```
struct GlobalConstants {
    static let someNotification = "TEST"
}
println(GlobalConstants.someNotification)
```

For further reference, refer to Swift Offical Guide or see the following link

[How to create a global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195262/swift-how-to-create-a-global-variable)

Comment: your answer though would allow something like `GlobalConstants()`, which doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

If all the constants are of the same type an `enum` could be the right way