# Getting value of variable from a class to another place

Tags: swift3

Let's say:

1. I have class `String` containing an empty string variable `a`
2. In page 1, I need to set variable a = "string here"
3. In page 2, I need to call the value of `a`

How can I do that?

Comment: means you want to pass the value from page 1 to page 2?

Comment: what is _'page'_ in this context?

Comment: page:  import UIKit

class APIurl {
    
    var loginURL = ""
    var trackingURL = ""
    var playbackURL = ""
    var feedbackURL = ""
    var geofenURL = ""

}

Comment: page2:  if item == "vnetgps.com" {
                self.api.trackingURL = "http://api.vnetgps.com:8000/tracking"
                self.api.playbackURL = "http://api.vnetgps.com:8000/playback"
                self.api.geofenURL =  "http://api.vnetgps.com:8000/geofence"
                self.api.feedbackURL = "http://api.vnetgps.com:8000/feedback"
                //let nextview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: <#T##String#>) as! APIurl
               // nextview.loginURL = "http://api.vnetgps.com:8000/trackin            
            }

Comment: Incorporate those comments into the question and you may get off of the Very Low Quality review queue where I found it.  At least you'll have some code to show some effort which your current post certainly doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from page 1

```
   let nextview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Page2Identifier") as! Page1Controller
nextview.prevscreen = a
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextview, animated: true)
```

in Page 2

```
var prevscreen = ""
```

Comment: between 2 class

Comment: can try with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202833/passing-data-between-swift-files-in-xcode

Comment: I dont Passing Data Between View Controllers. I want Passing Data Between class