# Swift - Declare a global NSDate without value

Tags: swift, nsdate, global

I want to create a global NSDate in my app, because I want to save the date of the first time ever the app has been opened in this variable. I wrote 
"var LaunchDate = NSDate()" before the declaration of the main class of the first view controller, and in the viewdidload, if it is the first time the app is opened, it saves the date into the global variable LaunchDate. But everytime I open the app, it saves the current date because of "var LaunchDate = NSDate()".
 I didn't find a solution, do you have any idea to declare a global date without that he gives the current date please?

Comment: Look at my answer... Write me if that did it @Oscar

Comment: Do you want to persist the date between launches?

Comment: @Anokrize I replied in a comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `NSUserDefaults` to store the value.

The code checks if a value exists.
If yes it reads the value, if no it writes the current date.

```
var launchDate : NSDate!

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let dateOfFirstLaunch = defaults.objectForKey("dateOfFirstLaunch") as? NSDate {
  launchDate = dateOfFirstLaunch
} else {
  let currentDate = NSDate()
  defaults.setObject(currentDate, forKey:"dateOfFirstLaunch")
  launchDate = currentDate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var LaunchDate: NSDate

    // when you want to set the value for it:
    LaunchDate = NSDate()
}
```

The Proble, is that NSDate() which you tried to do is a function, which gets back a value of the current date.

Comment: Thank you but you don't exactly answer the problem, I want LaunchDate to be a global variable (to use it in another ViewController)

Comment: Then the approach would be to create a struct and you can access the variable from anywhere

Comment: @Oscar look at this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html. Structs have the advantage that you can use them all over your classes. Then you can simply access the variable and its values

Comment: Great ! Do you have an example please ?

Comment: Yes look above @Oscar

Comment: Just make a new file as you would for a class and then write your variables into this structure

Comment: I am going to try with this way :)

Comment: Good! Remember to add the attribute static in a struct

Answer (score 0):

> Global variables are variables that are defined outside of any
>   function, method, closure, or type context

```
struct globalDate 
{
   static var LaunchDate = NSDate()
}
```

In swift if you encapsulate the variable in struct, you can access that in any classes.

[Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

[Global Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195262/how-to-create-a-global-variable)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Singleton Pattern with `NSUserDefaults`.

The code should be something like this

```
import Foundation

class UserDefaults {
    static let sharedInstance = UserDefaults()

    var launchDate: NSDate? {
        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("launch_date") as? NSDate
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue, forKey: "launch_date")
        }
    }
}
```

Access it using this code

```
UserDefaults.sharedInstance.launchDate
```