# Am I doing this correctly? Swift 3 xcode loading data from firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

The way I currently load my data is in the viewWillAppear on their specific view controllers. My question is should I load all the data on the Home/Main View Controller and pass the data that way? Or is the current way Im doing it better?

I know this is subjective, I'm loading ALOT of data.

Comment: You may want to retrieve your data when the app launches, and then pass the data with global variables.

Comment: 'ViewDidAppear' might cause serious delays, you should not use it IMO

Comment: @Xcoder123 How do I do that? DO they reset/clear if the application is closed?

Comment: Yes, they do. An alternative is UserDefaults

Comment: Or core data is even better for large amounts of data

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll check it out. I was just skeptical using A TON of UserDefaults, so I switched to what I believe is a global variable.

Comment: Yes, user defaults aren't really the place for large data. Good luck!

Comment: [How to create a Global Variable in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195262/how-to-create-a-global-variable) may help. Take a look over that!

Answer (score 1):

### Structure:

If you do not want the data to persist between app processes (when the app is closed the data is cleared), you can use **[Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195262/how-to-create-a-global-variable)**. When it comes to retrieving data, I suggest you to create a function in AppDelegate called `retrieveFromFirebase()`, containing every piece of code needed to retrieve data in your app, for all the `UIViewControllers` of your app. Then you should call it inside

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {}
```

Then, inside your function, you should assign the snapshot's value to the global variable declared earlier.

### Example:

This is an example of how to setup `AppDelegate.swift` for this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase

//declaration of the global variable
var username = String()

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()
        retrieveFromFirebase()
        return true
    }

    func retrieveFromFirebase(){
        // get the data from Firebase
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("username").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
            username = snapshot.value! as! String
        })

    }

  // other methods from AppDelegate.swift

  }
```

And when you get to the desired `ViewController`, set your `viewDidAppear` function to this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     yourLabel.text = username
}
```

And you can just use your username anywhere in the current [Module](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Be aware that you should not force-unwrap the snapshot's value if you're not sure that it's not nil. If it may be nil, use guard-statements instead of `snapshot.value!`