# When transferring variables from two different views into one the variables get replaced

Tags: ios, swift, variables

So I'm making a shopping app for a school project and how it works is I have multiple views with two of them being for the actual product and one being the cart. When the user clicks on a product view a variable gets transferred to the cart view and fills a label. I used this method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var mainController = segue.destination as! CartViewController
    mainController.xCart = selected
    mainController.xPrice = xPrice
}
```

and basically the variable "selected" gets transferred to cart and it fills a label. On the other product view I have pretty much the same setup just with different variable names.

My problem is that when I select a product it goes in fine. But when I go back and add another product the first one gets pretty much deleted. It fill the label it's supposed to but the label from the other product is empty.

Comment: Honestly, just use "a global" for this simple learning project.  later, learn to use singletons.  (In reality the app would just be nothing like this, at all - it would connect in an OCC manner to some sort of cloud system.  So it's not like you're doing it "wrong".)

Answer (score 2):

In a real world app, for an offline cart, instead of using a global variable, you can create a singleton `Cart` object and have your products added to it in the form of array. You can access your cart from any view controller, for example `CartViewController`. It seems that you're creating a new instance of `CartViewController` every time which will not hold your old variables. Anyway, a global variable can do the job for you for this specific simple project.

**Example (Singleton):**

```
//Item object to add to cart
class Item: NSObject {
    
    var itemName: String = String()
    var itemDescription: String = String()
    var itemPrice: Float = Float()
    
    convenience init(itemName: String, itemDescription: String, itemPrice: Float) {
        self.init()
        self.itemName = itemName
        self.itemDescription = itemDescription
        self.itemPrice = itemPrice
    }
    
    override var description: String {
        return "\n\nItem Name: \(self.itemName)\nItem Description: \(self.itemDescription)\nItem Price: $\(self.itemPrice)\n"
    }
    
}

//The Cart shared object
class Cart: NSObject {
    
    static let sharedInstance = Cart()
    private var cartItems: [Item] = []
    
    var items: [Item] {
        return self.cartItems
    }
    
    override private init() {}
    
    func addItem(_ item: Item) {
        self.cartItems.append(item)
    }
    
    func removeLastItem() {
        if self.cartItems.count > 0 {
            self.cartItems.removeLast()
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Usage:**

```
Cart.sharedInstance.addItem(Item.init(itemName: "First Item",
                                      itemDescription: "Item description 1",
                                      itemPrice: 9.99))
Cart.sharedInstance.addItem(Item.init(itemName: "Second Item",
                                      itemDescription: "Item description 2",
                                      itemPrice: 99.99))

print("*****Added 2 items to cart*****")
print(Cart.sharedInstance.items)


Cart.sharedInstance.removeLastItem()
print("*****Removed 1 item from cart*****")
print(Cart.sharedInstance.items)
```

**Console Output:**

```
*****Added 2 items to cart*****
[

Item Name: First Item
Item Description: Item description 1
Item Price: $9.99
, 

Item Name: Second Item
Item Description: Item description 2
Item Price: $99.99
]
*****Removed 1 item from cart*****
[

Item Name: First Item
Item Description: Item description 1
Item Price: $9.99
]
```

Comment: You might have to post an example just to make things very clear.

Comment: Alright. I actually didn't know how to do this so I did some research and came to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195262/how-to-create-a-global-variable). I just put a struct in the app delegate and seems to work.

Comment: @AdamZyluk Check edited answer. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that make a global variable by placing a struct with you variable inside the app delegate like so:

```
struct MyVariables {
 static var yourVariable = "someString"
}
```

Then put this to acsses you variable:

```
MyVariables.yourVariable
```

Got this from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195262/how-to-create-a-global-variable)