# Populating textField from global variable fails

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I am fairly new to Swift and I am using Adafruit's Basic Chat iOS app https://github.com/adafruit/Basic-Chat that uses BLE and I am adding my own viewController and pushing that instead of the one Adafruit provides. My ViewController (ServoViewController) appears as expected.

I am communicating with an Arduino over BLE and receiving data from the Arduino and am parsing the relevant part (and printing to terminal) the data in the BLECentralViewController file.

I have set up a String variable outside of the BLECentralViewController class (so from my understanding it should be global). I read data into that variable in the BLECentralViewController and again print it successfully.

I then try to use that String variable to populate a textField in my viewController, however the textField never gets written to.

In the BLECentralViewController file I have the variables declared outside of the class like this:

```
var dataReceived: String = ""
public var batteryVal: String = "" // global variable
```

I check the incoming data from the Arduino. If it contains the String "Battery" I know it is the battery data. I can receive and get the substring (the battery %) and print it to the terminal.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

        if characteristic == rxCharacteristic {
            if let ASCIIstring = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                characteristicASCIIValue = ASCIIstring
                print("Value Received: \((characteristicASCIIValue as String))")
                dataReceived = (characteristicASCIIValue as String)

                if dataReceived.contains("Battery:")    {
                    print ("Battery value: ", dataReceived)
                    print("Substring: ", dataReceived.substring(from: 8))
                    batteryVal = dataReceived.substring(from: 8)
                    print("Printing batteryVal: ", batteryVal)

                }
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: nil)
                cvcrd.reportValvePosition()

            }
        }
    }
```

In my viewController (ServoViewController) I have the following function

```
func reportBatteryPercent() {
        // print battery value here
        batteryField.text = batteryVal
        print("Reporting Battery Percentage here...", batteryVal)
    }
```

To start with I just wanted to populate the textField when ServoViewController first loads, so I called reportBatteryPercent() in viewDidLoad().
In the terminal output window I see that "Reporting Battery Percentage here..." appears, but there is no value printed in the terminal output for batteryVal and batteryField.text is empty.

Since I am pushing my ServoViewController there is no segue, so I figured a global variable would be an easy way to access that data.
What am I doing wrong with accessing the global variable from my viewController?

EDIT: As per recommendations I have put the reportBatteryPercent() in viewWillAppear like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        reportBatteryPercent()
    }
```

However the data still doesn't print when in the ServoViewController.
I tried changing the declaration of the String from:

```
public var batteryVal: String = ""
```

to:

```
public var batteryVal: String = "999"
```

and now it prints 999 in the textField. So the problem now seems to be ServoViewController reading the batteryVal string after it has been updated by the BLECentralViewController

EDIT 2: I have confirmed the above my going back to the first viewController (BLECentralViewController) and then returning to the second viewController (ServoViewController). The correct value is now displayed.

I am away from my Apple machine now, but perhaps I could fix this by when I go to push the second ViewController, I could see if the value of interest is an empty string and sleep for a second? 
Would this sleep the main thread? 
If so how would I sleep the thread that is doing the push of the viewController?

Comment: Do any of your print statements in the `if dataReceived.contains("Battery:")` block print anything?

Comment: @GntlmnBndt all of those blocks print as expected. Its only when I go to the other viewController (ServoViewController) that the print statements fail to print the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `reportBatteryPercent` in `viewWillAppear`. And you will get what you want.

Here may be some problems: global variables are empty before `viewDidLoad`, or just your controller is not prepared to handle this vars.

To check it, set starting values of global vars to **non-empty** strings.

Comment: there is no difference , if it's empty it'll be in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

> Since I am pushing my ServoViewController there is no segue, so I figured a global variable would be an easy way to access that data

No you still can send value to the next vc like

```
let vc = stroybard.....
vc.someProperty = // value
self.navigationController?.push
```

plus you're discouraged from using global vars as they're confusing

---

`didUpdateValueFor`  is an asynchnous method so you need to make sure that the varaible you declare as global has a correct value when you push

Comment: So it seems the issue is that didUpdateValueFor is running after the viewController push gets called. Can you suggest how I could get the right value before the push?

Comment: you can't , only you can do the push inside the callback of `didUpdateValueFor`

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are lazy, so you cannot depend on them. You should either have the variable as a static in a struct or in a class with a singleton reference.

See [How to create a global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195262/how-to-create-a-global-variable) for more info.