# How to play a sound just one time SWIFT

Tags: xcode, swift, audio

I'm having a little problem with my code who consists to play a sound when I start my app. But here's the problem everytime that I go back to the first screen the sound is playing again and I want it to play just one time. When the menu screen pop ups for the fist time.

Here's my code

```
   var bubbleSound: SystemSoundID!
 bubbleSound = createBubbleSound()
 AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(bubbleSound)
```

(...)

the function

```
func createBubbleSound() -> SystemSoundID {
            var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0
    let soundURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), "bubble", "wav", nil)
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &soundID)
    return soundID

}
```

Comment: Where is `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(bubbleSound)` located? Is this in your `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: yes! in my ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `struct` like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24868789/5181636)):

```
struct MyViewState {
    static var hasPlayedSound = false
}
```

Then in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
if(!MyViewState.hasPlayedSound) {
    var bubbleSound: SystemSoundID!
    bubbleSound = createBubbleSound()
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(bubbleSound)
    MyViewState.hasPlayedSound = true
}
```

You can then modify `MyViewState.hasPlayedSound` and allow the `UIViewController` to play the sound again if desired.